# Combining CSV files using task scheduler

Tags: csv, powershell, automation

I am trying to combine multiple CSV files into one and trying to automate the process.

Location of CSV files: `c:/users/name/test`

file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv

Script I have that works:

```
@(Import-csv file1.csv) + @(Import-csv file2.csv) + @(Import-csv file3.csv) |
    Export-csv Total.csv
```

Issue I have is I am using Task Scheduler with PowerShell I have to open it up first and change the directory to where the .csv files are so `CD` or `Set-Location c:/users/name/test` and after I have to execute the script above not sure how do one after another and automate it.

1. open powershell
2. change directory
3. run script

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things:

- Set the working directory of the scheduled task to `c:/users/name/test`. That way your script will automatically be running in that folder.
- Run `Set-Location 'c:/users/name/test'` to change the folder inside the script.
- Use full paths in the script.

I'd recommend the latter. if the folder doesn't contain other CSVs you could simplify the script to something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\name\test' -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
  Import-Csv $_.FullName
} | Export-Csv 'C:\users\name\test\total.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution out of the box "if you can use CMD" simply write :

C:\yourdirWhereCsvfilesExist\copy *.csv combinedfile.csv

then you will have a single file called combinedfile.csv with all the data

I hope that's will be helpful for you!